# Prevent Discovery of Port from NMAP scan using -Pn

Tags: nmap, ports

Is there a way to prevent a port from being discovered by nmap? I found that port 1433 is still being flagged as "open" when using the following command:

```
nmap <ip_add> -Pn -p1433
```

or

```
nmap <ip_add> -Pn
```

However, it's not detected if I don't use -Pn and instead have just

```
nmap <ip_add> -p1433
```

Is there anyway to prevent this from being discovered?

Answer (score 2):

With `-Pn` it simply assumes that the host is online, even if various heuristics (ICMP ping and others) fail. `-p1433` will then only check if this specific port is open.

Since you are explicitly running a service on this port which should be reachable from outside, it will also be reachable for detection by nmap, i.e. you cannot simply hide it from nmap.

But depending on the kind of service you offer you might restrict access only to specific IP addresses using firewall rules, in which case it will only be detectable by nmap originating from these allowed locations. Or you might use techniques like [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) to make the service only accessible after some secret packet handshake - but this would need to be implement at each client which should use the service.